# Wagtail autogenerated slug with id

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to create PersonPage without title field, but with fields “surname” and “name” and also I want it to generate slug (at saving) “surname-name-id” where “id” is private key (id, or page_ptr_id) from database.
What should I use to solve that issue?

I tried to create custom form and make class PersonPage based on that form — it helped me get rid of title, but I have no access to id

I used code from [Wagtail Page title overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625770/wagtail-page-title-overwriting)

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm


class NoTitleForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False, disabled=True, help_text=_('Title is auto-generated.'))
    slug = forms.SlugField(required=False, disabled=True, help_text=_('Slug is auto-generated.'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.initial['title']:
            self.initial['title'] = _('auto-generated-title')
        if not self.initial['slug']:
            self.initial['slug'] = _('auto-generated-slug')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        page = super().save(commit=False)

        new_title = strip_tags(self.cleaned_data['surname'])+' ' strip_tags(self.cleaned_data['name'])
        page.title = new_title
        page.slug = slugify(new_title)

        if commit:
            page.save()
        return page
```

and

```
# ... imports omitted for brevity


class PersonPage(Page):

    base_form_class = NoTitleForm
    surname = RichTextField()
    name = RichTextField()



    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('surname'),
                FieldPanel('surname'),
            ],
            heading=_('Metadata')
    )]
```

it worked fine, but I want something like this for slug

```
new_title = strip_tags(self.cleaned_data['surname'])+' ' strip_tags(self.cleaned_data['name']) + ' ' + self.cleaned_data['id']
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have so far? Also see this issue for others trying to solve a similar problem. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/161

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.